# Why excel worksheet name has (2) in it?

Tags: vb.net, excel, worksheet-function

I am using following VB.NET code to copy an excel sheet in a same workbook, but the sheet names are written with (2) every time, what is wrong here?

```
Dim inp as Integer
inp=Val(Textbox1.Text)

oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("D:\testfile.xlsx")
oSheet = oWB.Worksheets("base")
With oWB
   For i = 0 To inp - 1
     oSheet.Copy(Before:=.Worksheets(i + 1))
     With oSheet
       .Name = "INP" & i + 1
     End With
   Next
End With
```

How to get rid of "(2)" on the sheet name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following line:

```
     oSheet.Copy(Before:=.Worksheets(i + 1))
```

is creating a copy of the sheet you specified.  when you create a copy of a sheet, excel adds `(2)` to the name to prevent having duplicate sheet names.

lets say for example you had a sheet named `base` that you were trying to copy.  after processing that line above, you'd end up with the original sheet named `base` and a new sheet named `base (2)`.

then, the next few lines of your code:

```
     With oSheet
       .Name = "INP" & i + 1
     End With
```

just rename the original sheet.

try this instead of those two lines:

```
     With oWB.Worksheets("base (2)")
       .Name = "INP" & i + 1
     End With
```

Comment: note: i can't test the suggested code as i don't have access to VB.NET right now, but the problem with the algorithm is what i primarily wanted to point out.

Answer (score 1):

Just reference the worksheet you created and rename it.  You just need  the line          Worksheets(i + 1).Name = "INP" & i + 1   see below

```
Dim inp as Integer
inp=Val(Textbox1.Text)

oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("D:\testfile.xlsx")
oSheet = oWB.Worksheets("base")
With oWB
   For i = 0 To inp - 1
     oSheet.Copy(Before:=.Worksheets(i + 1))
     'reference and name worksheet
     Worksheets(i + 1).Name = "INP" & i + 1
   Next
End With
```